# Linq, is select().SingleorDefault() a bad idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
 var queueitem = context.CrawlerQueues.
                 Select(cq => new{cq.Guid,cq.Result}).
                 SingleOrDefault(cq => cq.Guid == guid);
```

Is above a bad idea, will it first select all database rows and then find the one or will it be smart and see the context its used within and only fetch the one row.

Reason for doing this is i want to return only the Guid and the Result coloums.

```
return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueitem, Formatting.Indented);
```

How would i find the answer to this without having to monitor network flow or the requests made to the database?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"will it first select all database rows and then find the one "

Technically, no, the combination of .Select followed by .SingleOrDefault will not do that.  Select() sets up the parameters for the query, but it doesn't actually fetch any data.  LINQ's deferred execution doesn't fetch any rows until something actually has to produce a data result. You can compose multiple queries together (.Select(...).Select(..) etc) and nothing actually fetches any rows until you perform an operation that returns data, such as First() or .ToList().

However, the use of Single() may result in scanning the entire dataset to prove that the one matching row is the only matching row.

Think about it: how will the query know that the one row is the *only* row in the dataset that matches? It will have to try to find the next row.  If there really is only one row that matches out of millions in the dataset, Single() may have to run through all of those millions of rows to prove the current match is the one and only match.

If your dataset is SQL, and your data is indexed in a manner that allows query optimization, then Single() might not be so bad.  But if your SQL data isn't indexed in a way that's helpful to this query, Single() may create a lot of work for the SQL server.

Single() is appropriate if your program logic really needs to know that the returned row is the one and only row in the entire dataset. However, there are other ways to guarantee uniqueness. If you can set up a primary key on your data that matches your LINQ condition, then only one matching row can exist / be added to the database to begin with, so you don't really need Single(). (And ironically, Single()'s performance will be trivially fast in this case too because the primary key index can be used to optimize the query)

If you just want the first row that matches the condition, use First() instead of Single().  First() only has to scan rows of data until it finds the first match.  It doesn't have to continue scanning rows to prove that the first match is the only match, like Single().

Comment: Thank you. I have been using firstordefault but when making the question i somehow forgot.

Comment: I was going to suggest FirstOrDefault() too.

Answer (score 3):

[`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) - Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; **this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence**.

[`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) - Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

Semantically, you want `FirstorDefault` since your question mentions multiple rows returned.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure this will not return the entire database prior to filtering as the execution of the query does not occur until after the 'evaluation' statement executes, which is the SingleOrDefault() in this query.

If you had

`context.CrawlerQueues.ToList().Select(cq => new{cq.Guid,cq.Result}).SingleOrDefault(cq => cq.Guid == guid)`;

then this would evaluate the `ToList()` before filtering, but the query as it stands is fine.

If you are unsure of the evaluation path or the generated SQL from your LINQ statements, [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a very good tool that makes working with Linq, Linq2Sql, EF very easy.

Answer (score 1):

The actual query executed actually depends on the Linq provider, but yes, the Linq provider will not evaluate until the last possible moment so it will know the context (SingleOrDefault) before executing the query. A good one won't fetch anything un-necessarily.

A good Linq implementation will actually fetch 2 rows, since SingleOrDefault takes care of 3 cases;

- No row returned -> returns default
- One row returned -> Returns that row
- More than one row returned -> Throw exception (Sequence contains more than one element)